# Hiding excel whilst SAS reads in Data

Tags: excel, sas, vba

I am using a well known piece of code to read an excel work book into SAS. The SAS code is called from Excel and then proceeds to open the required SAS work book and read the data into a SAS data set. The problem that I have is that while the code is being read in, we can see how SAS runs through the data set.

Is there a way to hide this? I realise the excel work book needs to be opened, but I would prefer it to stay minimised so that I don't see all the jumping around the work book. Furthermore, if you click anywhere during the read in process, the process fails. I am not sure if hiding the work book will also fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you're using DDE. It helps if you can post the code. There have been many improvements in SAS in the years since DDE was popular so you can likely use PROC IMPORT to read the code now, but without knowing more details its hard to say. Specifically, is it reading entire tabs, or select fields.  Are the read in ranges dynamic or fixed?

Comment: Yip, I am using DDE. I have an excel book with a large number of tabs whose data is constantly varying, thus I need very flexible code that can run through the whole book. I have based my code on the well known xl2sas macro.

Comment: You can now point a libref to an XLSX file and treat it like a SAS library. Using PROC CONTENTS, PROC COPY etc.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I will look into that! I am still interested in minimising the excel window in the current code, if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll have to provide some sample structure to your workbook for concrete ideas, but in general there should be better solutions today. I'm not familiar with xl2sas macro, but I looked it up. Looks like it's from 2006 (SUGI 30) and SAS 8.2 which are at least a decade old now.

Comment: Option XMIN or apps.minimize should minimize the Excel Window, but you still won't be able to interact with your computer while it's running. http://comp.soft-sys.sas.narkive.com/0D15Iupt/running-excel-minimized-while-running-sas-and-doing-dde

Comment: I have tried both of those solutions. xmin does not work at all, while apps.minimize minimizes the window from working but simply stops the code too.

Comment: btw, looked into the libref and it wont work as I am running 9.2 :(

Comment: Is your file XLS or XLSX? If it's XLS you can use libname EXCEL

Comment: xlsx. The xmin doesn't work as I am not using an x statement ;)

Comment: application.screenupdating and application.interactive can be set to FALSE in Excel (they're accessible via VBA , and perhaps in DDE as well?)  IE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841248.aspx

Comment: There is an [Application.Visible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198119.aspx) property if you have access to the Excel.Application object.

Comment: I think in theory `APPLICATION.INTERACTIVE` is what you want, but I can't get it to work - it seems to make DDE not work, despite Microsoft suggesting that it ought to.

Answer (score 0):

Using SAS 9.3 and Excel 2010 this worked for me, it's app.minimize (not apps.minimize()).

However, you still cannot work with your computer.

```
options noxwait noxsync;

x '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE"';

data _null_;
z=sleep(1);
run;

filename cmds dde 'excel|system';

data _null_;
file cmds;
put '[open("C:\_LOCALdata\air.xlsx")]';
x=sleep(1);
run;

data _null_;
file cmds;
put "[app.minimize()]";
x=sleep(2);
run;
```

Comment: When I tested doing this, DDE stopped sending the DDE commands to that excel workbook when it minimized.

Comment: That possibly true, but it does minimize the Window. The answer to the question may be that it can't be done the way the OP wants. I'll honestly say I don't see a point to this.  Whether you see it or not, it's occupying your computer. Migrate to a libname or Proc Import methodology.

Comment: Or migrate to a coffee shop for a snack.

Comment: Yeah, or something you do before you leave for lunch, or the day.

Comment: It seems all minimization and screen-updating stops the code

Comment: I hate seeing things running. Perhaps I can open a screen that says "SAS is busy" that covers the workbook?

Comment: And yeas, I realise there are other solutions, but I am trying to get THIS ti work the way I want :)

Comment: It's not just that SAS is busy, your entire computer is busy. You can't do anything else while using DDE.

Comment: So would I not even be able to open some sort of dialog box that "locks" the screen and prevents accidental clicks ending the DDE?

Comment: I'll hesitate to say it's impossible, but I think it's highly unlikely. DDE seems to want Excel front and center while it interacts with it. This makes some sense as its replicating clicks in some manners.